# Does IntelliJ have a "Diff Summary View" (Structure Compare) like Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am an Eclipse user as well. Eclipse's diff view has an extra section, that summarizes changes:
[image]

I find this quite handy to get an overview of all changes.

Does Intellij have something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Intellij IDEA does not have a direct counterpart of the **Java Structure Compare** pane in Eclipse,but it does have something that is somewhat similar for giving an overview of changes: **[Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html)**:

> IntelliJ IDEA uses **Local History** to constantly track all changes made
>   to projects. Unlike version control systems that show differences
>   between specific commits, **Local History** automatically maintains
>   revisions for all meaningful events. This produces a detailed timeline
>   of changes in project structure and source code, with the ability to
>   roll back to any point if necessary.
>
> **To view Local History**:
>
> - On the VCS menu, point to **Local History**, and then click **Show History**...
>
> **To revert to a specific revision**:
>
> - Select it from the list and click **Revert** on the toolbar...

It's actually very powerful because it allows you to revert changes independently of any source control system. Here's a screen shot of my **Local History** to give you a better idea:

[image: LocalHistory]

The changes made are summarized in the column on the left of the screen. It's probably not quite what you were looking for, but it's still worth a look. Just be mindful of [limitations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html):

> Local History is not a replacement for proper source control.
>
> It is cleared when you install a new version of IntelliJ IDEA or
>   invalidate caches. It has a retention period and maximum size, so
>   revisions are not guaranteed to persist forever.
>
> Local History is not available for contents of binary files.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no compare-by-structure view, in IntelliJ, you could collapse unchanged elements, so Diff tool will show you only changed chunks.
[image]